# Is there any way to create a internal table from external table in hive using talend

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, talend

Suppose I have an external table and I want to create an internal table from it like "as select" in oracle. Is there any way in talend or using hive query

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by using `tHiveRow` component. In the component at the query section provide the below query to create the `internal table` from an existing `external table`.

Query -

```
CREATE TABLE `internaltablename` LIKE `externaltablename`;
```